# about vector by using class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I need some helps with my code!
Here is some instruction:

- > v.**mul**(other) : If other is of type Vector , returns the dot > product of v and other , which is the sum of the products of the >
  >   corresponding components; raises an assertion error if other is of >
  >   different dimension. If other is of type int or float , returns a new
  >   vector resulting from the scalar multiplication of v with other . If > the type of other is not Vector , int , or float , raises an
  >   assertion > error.
- v.**rmul**(other) : Defined exactly like    v.**mul**(other)

========================================================================

Here is the code:

```
class Vector(object):
   vec = []
   def __init__(self, l):
       self.vec = l
   def dim():
       return len(self.vec)
   def __getitem__(self, i):
       return self.vec[i - 1]
   def __setitem__(self, i, x):
       self.vec[i - 1] = x
   def __str__(self):
       s = 'Vector: ['
       for i in range(0, len(self.vec)):
           s = s + str(self.vec[i])
           if i < len(self.vec) - 1:
               s = s + ', '
       s = s + ']'
       return s
   def __add__(self, other):
       assert(type(other) == Vector)
       v = self.vec
       for i in range(0, len(v)):
           v[i]=v[i] + other[i+1]
       x = Vector(v)
       return x
   def __mul__(self, other):
       if type(other) == type(self):
           v = self.vec
           for i in range(0, len(v)):
               v[i]=v[i]*other[i+1]
               x = Vector(v)
           return sum(x)
       elif type(other) == type(1) or type(other) == type(1.0):
           v = self.vec
           for i in range(0, len(v)):
               v[i] = v[i] *other
               x = Vector(v)
           return x

   def __rmul__(self, other):
       return self.__mul__(other)
```

Here are some output from the code:

```
>>> v1 = Vector([2, 3, 4]); v2 = Vector([1, 2, 3])
>>> print(v2 * 2); print(2 * v2)
Vector: [2, 4, 6]
Vector: [4, 8, 12]
>>> print(v1 * v2); print(v2 * v1)
128
1376
```

But, the correct output is:

```
>>> v1 = Vector([2, 3, 4]); v2 = Vector([1, 2, 3])
>>> print(v2 * 2); print(2 * v2)
Vector: [2, 4, 6]
Vector: [2, 4, 6]
>>> print(v1 * v2); print(v2 * v1)
20
20
```

So, I want to know what the problem is and how to fix it.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This method gives the desired output:

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
        if len(self.vec) != len(other.vec):
            raise AssertionError('Vectors have different lengths '
                                 'of {} and {}'.format(len(self.vec), len(other.vec)))
        return sum(x * y for x, y in zip(self.vec, other.vec))
    elif isinstance(other, (int, float)):
        return Vector([x * other for x in self.vec])
    else:
        raise AssertionError('Cannot use type ' + str(type(other)))
```

Comment: Thanks! But, when i add return "Vector:  "+ [x * other for x in self.vec] it is wrong

Comment: can you help me? please!